# Is it possible to redirect a url to another url so that users see always the original url?

Tags: iis, redirect, rewrite

I have a website whose url is subdomain.example.com but I want users to use a different url to access it, example.com/subdomain.
Just to add a bit of context, the two domains are on two separate servers, on different technologies, so I cannot put them on the same server.
I know I can do redirect from one to the other but for marketing reasons end users cannot see the redirected url in the address bar but always the one they typed.

Is this possible? How to implement it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible solutions:

1) Use iframes and inside the iframe open the other URL.

2) Use something like [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) on apache httpd or whatever the equivalent if your webserver is.

Comment: Thank you, I'm on IIS.. I'll try to look something similar... looks like ARR (http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) might do the trick

Comment: Yes, based on what I found on the internet about ARR this would do the trick.